# Isoslides presentation, incremental bullet points for subsections

Tags: r, slideshow, ioslides

In an isoslides_presentation, creating incremental (in terms of time: one after another) bullet points can be done by following code:

```
> - point 1
> - point 2
```

But how do I achieve this for lower hierarchy points?
Something like this (both not working):

```
> - point 1
>   - subpoint 1.1
>   - subpoint 1.2
> - point 2
>   - subpoint 2.1
>   - subpoint 2.2
```

or this

```
> - point 1
  > - subpoint 1.1
  > - subpoint 1.2
> - point 2
  > - subpoint 2.1
  > - subpoint 2.2
```

I found a reference (https://rpubs.com/eli_3357/ioslides), that states:

> A section can also be incremental
> using > * for the first line, and >tab* for the following lines"

But I can not get it to run.

In reply to the comment, here is a more complete RepEx:

```
---
title: "Test"
subtitle: "I do tests"

output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    smaller: yes
  slidy_presentation: default
---

# Slide 1

> - Point 1: to show after first click
>   - point 1.1: to show after second click 
>   - point 1.2: to show after third click 
> - Point 2: to show after fourth click
>   - and so on ...

#######################################

# Slide 2 {.build}

> - I'm, aware of the build-option...
>   - ...but this also gives not the intended result ...
>   - ... and all sub-bullets appear at once
```

Comment: You should put together a full reproducible example.  It should just need one slide...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "18/10/2022"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
  - Sub-bullet 1
  - Sub-bullet 2
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
````

[image]

Comment: Indeed this works, but how to get the sub-bullets to appear incremental?

Comment: How much more incremental do you want?  Are the indent and change of bullet not sufficient?  Define your terms.  As @user2554330 has suggested, we need more details - in other words, a minimal reproducible expample - to provide more specific advice.

Comment: Ok, I try to be more precise. Incremental refers to one after another in terms of time not space. I want that in the first step only the first bullet is visible. Then, after a mouse click the first sub-bullet should appear. And so on...

Comment: "... to show after first click" etc is a critical piece of information that was completely missing from your original post.

Comment: It seems that this was lost in translation. As native german speaker I wasn't aware of the "spatial" meaning of the word incremental.